# how to disable ctrl+esc shortcut windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, start-menu, ctrl

Pressing ctrl+esc opens the windows start menu.. I'd like to disable this shortcut but still have normal functionality of ctrl and esc individually. Is this possible?